# Magento2: Got the issue

Tags: magento2, product-images, aws

I have installed the Magento2-S3 extension for Aws S3 storage.

I have got the issue below when I run the command php bin/magento s3:storage:export

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found in /var/www/html/public_html/app/code/Thai/S3/Console/Command/StorageExportCommand.php:98
```

**PHP StorageExportCommand file**

```
<?php
namespace Thai\S3\Console\Command;

use Magento\Framework\App\Area;
use Magento\Framework\App\State;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\Storage\Database;
use Magento\MediaStorage\Helper\File\StorageFactory;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Thai\S3\Helper\Data as DataHelper;

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
class StorageExportCommand extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var State
     */
    private $state;

    /**
     * @var DataHelper
     */
    private $helper;

    /**
     * @var Storage
     */
    private $coreFileStorage;

    /**
     * @param State $state
     * @param Database $storageHelper
     * @param StorageFactory $coreFileStorageFactory
     * @param DataHelper $helper
     */
    public function __construct(
        State $state,
        Database $storageHelper,
        StorageFactory $coreFileStorageFactory,
        DataHelper $helper
    ) {
        $this->state = $state;
        $this->coreFileStorage = $coreFileStorageFactory->create();
        $this->helper = $helper;

        parent::__construct();
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this->setName('s3:storage:export');
        $this->setDescription('Sync all of your media files over to S3.');
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     *
     * @throws \Exception
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        return $this->state->emulateAreaCode(Area::AREA_ADMINHTML, function () use ($output) {
            $errors = $this->validate();

            if ($errors) {
                $output->writeln('<error>' . implode('</error>' . PHP_EOL . '<error>', $errors) . '</error>');

                return 1;
            }

            $options = [
                'version' => 'latest',
                'region' => $this->helper->getRegion(),
                'credentials' => [
                    'key' => $this->helper->getAccessKey(),
                    'secret' => $this->helper->getSecretKey(),
                ],
            ];

            if ($this->helper->getEndpointEnabled()) {
                if ($this->helper->getEndpoint()) {
                    $options['endpoint'] = $this->helper->getEndpoint();
                }

                if ($this->helper->getEndpointRegion()) {
                    $options['region'] = $this->helper->getEndpointRegion();
                }
            }

            try {
                $client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client($options);
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                $output->writeln(sprintf('<error>%s</error>', $e->getMessage()));

                return 1;
            }

            if (!$client->doesBucketExist($this->helper->getBucket())) {
                $output->writeln('<error>The AWS credentials you provided did not work. Please review your details and try again. You can do so using our config script.</error>');

                return 1;
            }

            if ($this->coreFileStorage->getCurrentStorageCode() === \Thai\S3\Model\MediaStorage\File\Storage::STORAGE_MEDIA_S3) {
                $output->writeln('<error>You are already using S3 as your media file storage backend!</error>');

                return 1;
            }

            $sourceModel = $this->coreFileStorage->getStorageModel();
            /** @var \Thai\S3\Model\MediaStorage\File\Storage\S3 $destinationModel */
            $destinationModel = $this->coreFileStorage->getStorageModel(\Thai\S3\Model\MediaStorage\File\Storage::STORAGE_MEDIA_S3);

            $offset = 0;
            while (($files = $sourceModel->exportFiles($offset, 1)) !== false) {
                foreach ($files as $file) {
                    $object = ltrim($file['directory'] . '/' . $file['filename'], '/');

                    $output->writeln(sprintf('Uploading %s to use S3.', $object));
                }
                $destinationModel->importFiles($files);
                $offset += count($files);
            }

            return 0;
        });
    }

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function validate()
    {
        $errors = [];

        if (null === $this->helper->getAccessKey()) {
            $errors[] = 'You have not provided an AWS access key ID. You can do so using our config script.';
        }
        if (null === $this->helper->getSecretKey()) {
            $errors[] = 'You have not provided an AWS secret access key. You can do so using our config script.';
        }
        if (null === $this->helper->getBucket()) {
            $errors[] = 'You have not provided an S3 bucket. You can do so using our config script.';
        }
        if (null === $this->helper->getRegion()) {
            $errors[] = 'You have not provided an S3 region. You can do so using our config script.';
        }

        return $errors;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per as, my understand that **`aws/aws-sdk-php`** package is missing.

> PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Aws\S3\S3Client' not found

because of `AWS SDK for PHP` package is missing and

This `Thai_S3` module is  required

```
"aws/aws-sdk-php": "3.x",
"symfony/console": "^2.6||^4.0",
"magento/module-captcha": ">=100",
"magento/module-cms": ">=100",
"magento/module-config": ">=100",
"magento/module-media-storage": ">=100",
"magento/framework": ">=100",
"magento/module-store": ">=100",
"magento/module-swatches": ">=100
```

Package, 
You have to install **`aws/aws-sdk-php`** https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php using composer.

Comment: Hi, I have downloaded the package. Can you tell me what is exact path of the aws/aws-sdk-php in my extension.

Comment: Also i have insatlled Thai_S3 module. But path is not getting me.

Comment: $client = new \Aws\S3\S3Client($options);

Comment: You have to   install package using composer

Comment: No, I have direct installed using zip file.

Comment: Now, I have freshly installed the module using composer. composer installed successfully then I have run the enable module  command got the error Autoload error: 'Thai_S3' component already exists masud@masud-ThinkCentre-M71e:/var/www/html/public_html$

Comment: Above issue is resolved. Upgrade command is successful.

Comment: Got the new error when i run the php bin/magento s3:storage:export [InvalidArgumentException]                                    
  There are no commands defined in the "s3:storage" namespace.

Comment: Hi, export command is working fine.

Comment: Export command run successfully but images not uploaded on S3 bucket. @AmitBera

Comment: Please contact with extension provider  and they will tell what is the issue